# Importing and exporting Set Associations (default programs) in Windows

Tags: windows, file-management, file-association, windows-installation

I like using portable programs. As an example, I have sublime text portable stored in D:/Apps/Developer/SublimeText3. For all my .php, .txt, .js, .scss, .css, etc... files, I set them to launch with sublime text. For some other files like .html, mpcpl, etc... I set sublime text as one of the options in "open with".

I was wondering, after I've done all that work, is there a way to save those, so that I can just import them with my next machine or when I reinstall Windows. Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to report the registry keys that handle this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Registry keys for the default/OpenWithList should be stored in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[extension]`(access via regedit.exe). From there, you can use `Export...` from the `File` menu, choose a destination and a name for it. When you want to use it on a different computer, open regedit, and choose `Import...`. You can export/import only certain extension settings, or all of them.